# how to handle outlook/windows live mail in selenium java

Tags: java, email, outlook

how to handle outlook/windows live mail in selenium java

```
   String host = "pop.gmail.com";
   String mailStoreType = "pop3";
   String username = "*****@****.com";
    String passwrd = "*******";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
         properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
         properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
         properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

         Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

         store.connect(host, username, passwrd);
```

But this was not working no response in the last line "store.connect(host, username, passwrd);"